# how can I set Network interface status?

Tags: python, linux, network-programming

In Python, is there a way to set network interface up or down ? i'm working with linux
In my script I would like to set the interface up and down ?

Comment: The easy way to to just exec `ip link set dev eth0 down` (replace eth0 accordingly). The modern, programmatic way would be to open a netlink socket and issue a RTM_SETLINK message with IFF_DOWN

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.system("ifdown eth0")
os.system("ifup eth0")
```

*NOTE:  make sure you connect the remote host with deferent interface  before run